# Momentum eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, wavefunction, eigenvalue

Is $e^{-\frac{|x|}{a}}$ an eigenfunction of momentum?

If we apply the momentum operator $\hat{P}=-i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ we get:

$$
-i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial x}e^{\frac{|x|}{a}}=\cases{i\hbar e^{-x/a}  \
 \ \  \ (x>0)\\-i\hbar e^{x/a}\ \ \ (x<0)}
$$

Which is a constant times the function, however the constant depends on $x$ and so I would say it is not an eigenfunction.

Comment: if the constant depends on $x$, it's not a constant...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Well, sgn(x) is constant on the left, it's constant on the right and whatever happens in the middle can be attributed to experimental error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an eigenstate of momentum in infinite 1D space [$x\in(-\infty;\infty)$]. The reason is that the absolute value is not analytic in that space. You can think of it in general terms: Let $\psi(x)=A\mathrm{e}^{if(x)}$, with dimensionless $A$ and $f(x)$. Then $$-i\hbar\partial_x\psi(x)=\hbar A\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\mathrm{e}^{if(x)}=C\psi(x)\Leftrightarrow C=\hbar \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}.$$

If $f$ is not differentiable everywhere inside the domain, then $\psi$ isn't an eigenfunction. You could redefine your domain to be only half space [$(-\infty,0]$ or $[0,\infty)$], but then what you have is simply $\mathrm{e}^{\pm ikx}$.

Comment: Hello David, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Thanks for your answer, hope to see you around the site!

Answer (score -1):

It is an eigenfunction of $p~=~-i\hbar\partial_x$ except at $x~=~0$. The derivative of the function $f(x)~=~e^{|x|/a}$ jumps discontinuously at $x~=~0$. We may approximate this with $f(x)~=~e^{\sqrt{\epsilon~+~x^2 }/a}$, for $\epsilon$ small. The derivative with respect to $x$ is
$$
\frac{d}{dx}~=~\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon~+~x^2}}e^{\sqrt{\epsilon~+~x^2 }/a}.
$$
In the limit $\epsilon~\rightarrow~0$ this is $\frac{x}{|x|}e^{\sqrt{\epsilon~+~x^2 }/a}$ or $sgn(x)e^{\sqrt{\epsilon~+~x^2 }/a}$.

Comment: Minor nitpick: The function is [perfectly continuous](http://imgur.com/F5nMPKr) at $x=0$, its [derivative](http://imgur.com/U6gI0qJ), however, is not.

Comment: Ouch, that is what I meant. I will revise.

Comment: sgn(x) depends on x. Therefore this isn't an eigenfunction. -1.

Comment: But that only pertains to the one point $x~=~0$

Comment: No, it doesn't. Eigenfunctions should return multiplied by a constant. sgn(x) is not a constant.